# Is there an elegant way to strip certain leading and trailing characters in Ruby (or Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string that may have a leading or trailing hyphen. I'd like to remove those.

My first thought is to reach for `strip`, which will remove one or more whitespace characters from either end. But surprisingly it refuses to strip anything else:

```
[3] pry(main)> "-thi-ng-".strip "-"
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

Do Ruby or Rails have an elegant way to express this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby

```rb
>> "---thi-ng---".gsub(/^-+|-+$/, "")
=> "thi-ng"
```

Rails

```rb
>> "---thi-ng---".remove(/^-+/, /-+$/)
=> "thi-ng"
```

Comment: Nice! This question has been marked as a duplicate, but these answers don't seem to be present on the old question, so I suggest you copy them there.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer that I can find is to chain two methods with rather long names:

```
"-thi-ng-".delete_prefix("-").delete_suffix("-")
=> "thi-ng"
```

Be aware that it doesn't handle repeating characters like you'd expect from `strip`:

```
"-thi-ng--".delete_prefix("-").delete_suffix("-")
=> "thi-ng-"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be using `gsub` with a regexg:

```
LEADING_OR_TRAILING_HYPEN_REGEXP = /^\-|\-$/

"-thi-ng-".gsub(LEADING_OR_TRAILING_HYPEN_REGEXP, '')
#=> "thi-ng"
```